# Is there an idiomatic 'to be desperate' usage (without 'for' or 'to')?

Tags: meaning

All dictionaries I have checked seem to agree on the basic meanings of 'desperate', but here are two instances I can't fit properly into any of the categories:

**Situation 1:** kid needs to go to the bathroom; mother asks:

*Are you desperate? Can't you wait till we get home?*

**Situation 2:** someone has no place to stay; friend says:

*You can stay here for a couple of days if you're desperate.*

It's not like these people are

- 'feeling or showing that they have little hope and are ready to do anything without worrying about danger to themselves or others' (Oxford Learners)
- 'very sad and upset because of having little or no hope' (MW)
- 'very worried and angry because they do not know how to deal with an
  unpleasant situation' (Macmillan)
- 'willing to do anything to change a very bad situation, and not
  caring about danger' (Longman)

Also, they are not 'violent', 'rash' or 'dangerous'.

The seemingly obvious solution is that they are

- 'needing or wanting something very much' (Oxford Learners / Macmillan / Cambridge)
- 'having a very great desire, need, etc.' (Longman)

However, all of these dictionary exclusively offer examples that have 'desperate **for**' and 'desperate **to**' in them. Not a single one reflecting the usage of my two examples, with a free-standing 'desperate'.

Are these unorthodox usages I shouldn't make much of, or something the dictionaries failed to include (either as a separate meaning, or a distinct kind of usage)?

Comment: They're fine in conversation, but I'd restrict the bare usage meaning 'having a very great desire, need, etc.' to informal registers.

Comment: If you are asking to use _deparate_ alone without a preposition, yes, you can do that very well. In _Gone With The Wind_, Scarlett became so hungry and **desperate** that she ate raw sweet potato from the field, dusty with soil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why these dictionaries don't seem to have a definition that fits because I find your examples to be perfectly idiomatic (as a native English speaker).

The definition (from my dictionary) that fits best here is:

> (of a person) having a great need or desire for something
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/desperate)</sub>

It may be listed as requiring *for* or *to*, but usage says otherwise. And usage is really what matters. Look for example at [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=desperate):

> Someone who wants something so bad they will go to extreme lengths to get it.
>   *actually laughing at Jakcs pick up lines? that is so desperate.*

That's the highest voted definition, and it's essentially the same as the one I quoted above **except it doesn't require *for*/*to***.

I would say that many of the runners-up are just specific versions of this same definition (there are a number that define the term as "desperate for a relationship"). It's interesting to note that definition 6 is exactly the definition you used in your first example.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an entry from the Merriam-Webster dictionary. I think two or even three of these meanings could fit pretty well with your examples. And BTW those examples are very common usages (at least in the US--I'm a native speaker from the US). It is true that we sometimes use it in these contexts a little melodramtically, though.

Merriam-Webster definition of desperate

1

a :  having lost hope

b :  giving no ground for hope

2

a :  moved by despair or utter loss of hope

b :  involving or employing extreme measures in an attempt to escape defeat or frustration

3:  suffering extreme need or anxiety

4:  involving extreme danger or possible disaster

5:  of extreme intensity < … a desperate languor descended heavily upon her, and she slept … — Elinor Wylie>

6:  shocking, outrageous

Comment: Instead of post every single meaning in an unformatted manner, try editing to post to only include the relevant definitions in a formatted manner. Right now, your answer is very hard to read and most will give up before finishing.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel that the definition matching the usage of my examples is number 3 (suffering extreme need or anxiety), which then goes on to provide these examples: <desperate for money> <desperate to escape> <celebrities desperate for attention>. So it's still a case of all dictionary examples having 'for' or 'to' in them.

Comment: @Hank - Often, new users learn our ways more easily if we show them how the first couple of times.

Comment: @MVS - Speaking of our ways -- comments are quick and grammar errors are overlooked if the meaning can be understood.

Comment: I think this is a helpful answer and have upvoted it.  The definition MVS found works well in the bathroom and couchsurfing examples given in the question.

Comment: @Bepe - desperate to pee, desperate to find a safe, dry, warm place to sleep.  The context makes it unnecessary to spell it out.